# Sequence function in Amazon Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, sequence-sql

I am not able to use the sequence function amazon athena.
It shows a syntax error saying : Not a window function: sequence

I wrote the following code :
SELECT sequence(1, 1) OVER () as seq_num
FROM <table_name>

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use ROW_NUMBER(). You can either use:

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(sequence(1, 5))
```

or

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as seq_num FROM campaign_lookup
```